# Debug and intercept a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to put some code into a stored procedure, that checks the hostname.

Example:

```
if HOST_NAME() = 'hostname2'
     PRINT 'we are hostname2';
```

Then put a breakpoint right there on the 'print 'we are hostname2'.

Then in my website, I will call that stored procedure, which has 'hostname2' and I would like to enter that breakpoint, since the hostname will indeed be hostname2. After I hit the breakpoint, I will just continue to debug the stored procedure like normal.

I know about SQL Server Profiler and that I can log results of a stored procedure, but this would be super handy and much easier/less error prone to debug stored procedures, and improve my productivity a lot, and potentially others too.

I hope the intention and explanation is clear.

I see this old article, showing how to do it, but its very old, if somebody can find an up-to-date article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/debugging-stored-procedures-cs

Check the paragraph with title

Step 2: Configuring the Website for Application Debugging

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the SQL? Breakpoints are for debugging. A deployed Stored Procedure can't have a breakpoint. You can break point in SSMS, if you're running that SQL directly, but you can't put a breakpoint into an object.

Comment: For what you've linked to work you need to have the whole database as an object in your VS project.  I'll admit, I'm not savvy on the application side of things, however, do you have it set up like that?

Comment: although I dont' like it too much, you can:

IF HOST_NAME = 'host2'
begin
   RAISERROR('host2', 16,1)
   return
end

Comment: @LiyaTansky, I don't like that either, but you're right. It will work.